# delete item from local database function doesn't work

Tags: java, android, database

```
//the following function 'listens to the click' - here we are using an 'item click listener' which gives you a number of which one was clicked
        lv_customerList.setOnItemClickListener((parent, view, position, id) -> {
            //getting the customer that was just clicked to send it to the method to delete
            //the parent of the listener is the listview
            CustomerModel clickedCustomer = (CustomerModel) parent.getItemAtPosition(position); //this tells me which person was just clicked
            //now we call the "deleteOne" function from the databaseHelper class
            dataBaseHelper.deleteOne(clickedCustomer);
            //now we update the list view
            ShowCustomersOnListView(dataBaseHelper);
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Deleted" + clickedCustomer,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        });
```

This is the code in the MainActivity

```
//creating a new function that will delete contents from a database
    public boolean deleteOne(CustomerModel customerModel) {
        //find customerModel in the database. if is is found, delete it and return true, otherwise return false

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        String queryString = "DELETE FROM" + CUSTOMER_TABLE + "WHERE"  + CUSTOMER_ID + " = " + customerModel.getId();

        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(queryString, null);

        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            return true;
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

And this is the code from the DatabaseHelper activity

I followed the https://youtu.be/312RhjfetP8 tutorial and copied the code exactly (although the android IDE suggested to change the...

```
new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener()
```

to a lambda (in the method in mainactivity)

But now whenever I click one of the rows (see video to understand what i mean) in the app - the app just crashes and I'm not sure why :(

Could someone please help me out?

Thank you so much!

Comment: Would you please attach `Logcat` screenshot of the error you are getting?

Comment: have you checked whether or not there are actually records with that id? Have you executed other crud  operations that did work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure that you miss a lot of space characters in the query String.

```
String queryString = "DELETE FROM" + CUSTOMER_TABLE + "WHERE"  + CUSTOMER_ID + " = " + customerModel.getId();
```

should be changed to

```
String queryString = "DELETE FROM " + CUSTOMER_TABLE + " WHERE "  + CUSTOMER_ID + " = " + customerModel.getId();
```

Answer (score -2):

```
DeleteBuilder<CustomerModel, Integer> deletebuilder = 
                    mcustomermodel.deleteBuilder();
```